# Removing White Space at Bottom of Page

Tags: html, css

Need to remove the white space from the bottom of my web page, not sure what's causing it, most likely a div. I've tried setting height of all elements, not successful. Could it be something with the footer or the Welcome div?

```css
/* * {
   border: 1px solid red !important;
}
*/

body {
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
  height: 100%;
}
#welcome {
  font-family: "Alfa Slab One", serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
  display: none;
}
#welcomediv {
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-family: "Alegreya SC", serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: none;
}
#About {
  height: auto;
  background: black;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#abouth1 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: "Alfa Slab One", serif;
  color: white;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}
#navbar {
  display: none;
}
#navbar li {
  float: left;
}
#navbar li a {
  font-family: "Alfa Slab One", serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
#homepageh1 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: "Alfa Slab One";
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px black;
  display: none;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}
h3 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Alegreya Sans SC";
  display: none;
}
li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
footer {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 25%;
  margin-left: 650px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
.fa {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
#moveleft {
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 300px;
}
#globe {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Alegreya Sans SC", serif;
  padding-left: 175px;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
#brandsp {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: -80px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#newdiv {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
#clockicon {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 345px;
  bottom: 212.5px;
}
#clock {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  bottom: 254.5px;
  padding-left: 510px;
  font-family: "Alegreya Sans SC", serif;
  font-size: 40px;
}
#clock a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#clock a:hover {
  color: grey;
}
#clockp {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 42.5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: -200px;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
#newdiv2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 65px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
#newdiv3 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 115px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
#newspapericon {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 590px;
  margin-left: 900px;
}
#newspaper {
  font-family: "Alegreya Sans SC", serif;
  color: white;
  bottom: 641.5px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: 900px;
}
#newspaperdiv1 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 65.5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Alegreya Sans SC", serif;
  margin-left: -130px;
}
#newspaperdiv2 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Alegreya Sans SC", serif;
  margin-left: -40px;
  bottom: 117.5px;
  a
}
#newspaperp {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Alegreya Sans SC", serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  bottom: 42.5px;
  margin-left: -70px;
}
#getstarted {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 90px;
  font-family: "Alfa Slab One", serif;
  color: white;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Global Hypebeast is a website for exploring street fashion all across the globe. From everything from Supreme to The Hundreds, Global Hypebeast has it all. This isn't your regular fashion website. 
                   I put in all the work myself to create a truly personalized website that brings fashion into the spotlight." />
  <title>Street Wear from Across the World</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="http://www.globalhypebeast.com/favicon.ico?v=2" />
  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa Slab One|Alegreya Sans SC|Alegreya SC|Space Mono' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="homepageh1">Global Hypebeast: Street Fashion Worldwide</h1>
  <ul id="navbar">
    <li><a class="active" href="http://www.globalhypebeast.com">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.globalhypebeast.com/brands">BRANDS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">NEWS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ENTERTAINMENT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h1 id="welcome">
   Mission Hypebeast
  </h1>
  <div id="welcomediv">
    Welcome to Global Hypebeast. I created this website with the intent of sharing street fashion from all around the globe. Street wear is becoming more prominent in cities all around the world, especially those with a high population such as Tokyo, New
    York, and Los Angeles. On this site, you will find street wear images, upcoming brand collaborations, and a general definition of what street fashion really is. If you haven't already acquired a taste for street wear, you will after spending time
    on my website. I promise you. Who doesn't want to be in the know of the world's most iconic fashion?
  </div>
  <div id="About">
    <h1 id=abouth1>
    Everything From Fashion To Entertainment
   </h1>
    <div id="moveleft">
      <i class="fa fa-globe fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <div id="globe">
        <p>
          Brands
        </p>
        <p id="brandsp">
          We've got fashion from Supreme,
          <br/>
          <div id="newdiv">Palace, Bape, Stussy, etc.</div>
        </p>
      </div>
      <i id="clockicon" class="fa fa-clock-o fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <div id="clock">
        <p>
          Articles
        </p>
        <p id="clockp">
          New articles are posted daily so
          <br/>
          <div id="newdiv2">you'll never miss out</div>
          <br/>
          <div id="newdiv3">on fashion again.</div>
        </p>
      </div>
      <i id="newspapericon" class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <div id="newspaper">
        <p>
          News
        </p>
        <p id="newspaperp">
          Entertainment and fashion
          <br/>
          <div id="newspaperdiv1">news combined creates the best experience</div>
          <br/>
          <div id="newspaperdiv2">for all things fashion.</div>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1 id="getstarted">
     Get started! Check out some posts!
    </h1>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Daniel Sigut</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's coming from your font-awesome CSS import. Please pare down your code to a *minimal* reproduction. E.g. remove everything that isn't related. This will usually help you find what's causing the problem yourself.

Comment: What do you suggest I change?

Comment: So, things like your doctype, most of the stuff in your `<head>`, styles that change color or background-color. Anything that does not affect your extra space at the bottom should be removed from the demo. Also you have some illegal markup, like a `div` inside of a `p` (`p` elements cannot contain block-level elements like div). Also remove anything that is set to `display: none` because it's obviously not contributing to the problem. Here is a more pared-down demo that removes a bunch of unrelated styles but still completely shows the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/2px64ra7/

Comment: Here is a reworked HTML and CSS snippet of your site layout that doesn't have invalid code and that follows a little bit better design practice: https://jsfiddle.net/2px64ra7/1/ tl;dr - If you find you're having to `position` every single element, you should approach your layout in a different way.

Comment: Holy cow, you really did clean it up lol. Thanks for that, but I just had to add some images and the space went away. at least on 1366x768 resolution that is...

Answer (score 2):

A good practice to find such bugs is to remove elements until you can identify which one is the source of your problem.

But here, your issue seems to come from the fact you position many element "relative", then move them using bottom: xx px; Therefore, they appear at the top, but the layout still includes the space they should occupy.

I would suggest you to refactor your code to avoid having to position elements pixel by pixel. Use "display: inline-block" to inline your elements and adjust the space between them using margins/paddings.

Answer (score 0):

just add this to your css:

```
html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  max-height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}

body {
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: When set to overflow:hidden it cuts off the Welcome div.

Comment: I meant the About div, my bad.

Comment: okay. let me try something else. I'll update my answer shortly

Comment: thing is that you are using `bottom` property too many times. almost on every item. so the cause is not a single item.

Comment: See how the white space in the tinypic picture is so large? I tried setting max-height but to no avail. I might start picking apart elements like the guy said to do below.

Comment: did my new answer work? I updated the answer after I posted the pic

Comment: I tried picking out elements and like I said it's gonna crash your whole page structure